# How to run tests using a custom WebApplicationInitializer?

Tags: spring, scala, spring-mvc, spring-test

```
class MyWebAppInitializer extends WebApplicationInitializer {
  def onStartup(servletContext: ServletContext): Unit = {
      ...
  }
}

@RunWith(classOf[SpringJUnit4ClassRunner])
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Array(classOf[MyConfig]),
    initializers=Array(classOf[MyWebAppInitializer]))     // <<< ERROR
class MyTest {
  ...
}
```

Complains about :

```
annotation argument needs to be a constant; found: classOf[MyWebAppInitializer]
```

UPDATE: @M. Deinum points out that only ApplicationContextInitializers are allowed here - so the error is a badly reported type mistmatch.

So... how can I use my own MyWebAppInitializer in order and test the functionality defined therein?

Comment: You can provide `ApplicationContextInitializer`s NOT `WebApplicationInitializer`s. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html#initializers--

Comment: Quite right (though I despair at Scala's error reporting, my supplied value _is_ a constant, but the error is a type mismatch). So, how to start my test with a custom WebApplicationInitializer -- Spring provides the ability to customize its onStartup (and people frequently do). Is there a way to test this customization in unit tests?

Comment: Have updated the question to reflect the remaining issue -- how to test a WebApplicationInitializer.

Comment: The `WebApplicationInitializer` is for bootstrapping your application it  works in conjunction with a `ServletContainerInitializer`. If you want to test it then simply test it. Create an instance, pass an instance of `MockServletContext` to the startup method and see if it does what you expect it does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your context configuration I don't see that you have a context loader listed.  The [AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/web/AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.html) will locate instances of [WebApplicationInitializer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current//javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) on your classpath, by adding this and removing the intializers (which, as you have noted, are for ApplicationContextInitializers and not WebApplicationInitializers) then you should be all set.

```
@RunWith(classOf[SpringJUnit4ClassRunner])
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ConfigClass.class, AnotherConfigClass.class}, loader=AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class))
class MyTest {
...
```

Here is a working example

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes={WebConfiguration.class, SecurityConfig.class}, loader=AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class)
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class AppTests {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void simple() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view().name("index"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "Sorry,you can't".
You could refer to this:
[Spring FrameworkSPR-10199
Add capability to use WebApplicationInitializer for testing Spring web applications](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10199)

Just as Sam Brannen said:

> Although Spring does provide mocks for the Servlet API, Spring does
>   not mock a Servlet container and currently has no intention to. Spring
>   has always focused on out of container integration testing. Fully
>   mocking a container is therefore beyond the scope of Spring's testing
>   support. Please see comments from Rossen and me above for further
>   details.